# Order failed in Control-M, Folder does not exist

Tags: control-m

I can't order my Smart Folder in Control-M, I'm getting the following error:

Action: Order, failed. Request  rejected by Data Center
CTM5703 FOLDER XXXX DOES NOT EXIST

I double checked the entire flow and I'm sure the parameters and actions are correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check for any UTF 8 characters in any description, this makes it impossible to sync with the server for the checkin

Comment: Thanks! It was exactly that, I was using especial characters in the description of a folder, I removed it and it worked.